# use java try-with-resources for object that's already constructed

Tags: java

I really like the java's try-with-resources behavior.  I'm wondering is it possible to use the same behavior for an already constructed resource?  for instance if I have to call open() on some resources can I call it as part of the try-with-resource and still have it be auto-closed, or even just pass the resource after I open it to have it close.

I suspect the answer is no, but just wanted to make sure I know of any useful syntax.

Comment: You could test it and provide the answer.

Comment: I tried, couldn't figure out how to do it, but doesn't mean I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `open()` method returns an object which implements AutoCloseable *and* it is legal to close the resource after `open()` is called, this will work. No magic here.

```
try (MyAutoCloseable resource = Foo.open()) {
    // .. do your work
}
```

Comment: This is pretty convenient. I must try this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this... All that matters is that your resources are *declared* in the statement; which means you can do something like this:

```
final Foo toBeOpened = ...;
toBeOpened.open();

try (
    final Foo opened = toBeOpened;
) {
    /* work with opened */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with resources with existing object example.

```
try (existing_instance) {
  // process data
} catch (Exception e) {
  // process exception
}
```